# SQL-like query across multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I've got this setup and running in an Access DB, but I'm having difficulty translating this into R.

Dataframe A:

```
ID, B1, B2, B3, group
1, 0.2, 0.4, 1000, red
...
4447, 0.4, 0.32, 800, blue
```

Dataframe B (mean of columns from Dataframe A, based on column "group":

```
ID, group, meanB1, meanB2, meanB3
1, red, 0.45, 0.313, 990.32
...
6, blue, 0.39, 0.289, 790.54
```

There's also a third Dataframe C, which is the standard deviation of columns in Dataframe A, again, based on column "group".

I have an equation (simplified here) that I want to calculate for each line of Dataframe A, but it requires an input from associated entry in Dataframe B, like so:

```
FuncZ <- function(a, b, c) {(((a - b)/c)^2)}
```

Where `a` is line from Dataframe A (e.g., 4477), and `b` from Dataframe B (e.g., red), and `c` from Dataframe C (e.g., red).

This is relatively easy in Access, but I'd like to do it the R way.

Comment: I'm really confused as to how the standard deviation can be "red".

Comment: Presumably the colors represent a key on which the three data frames are linked...? Possibly a `merge` and then `apply` with an anonymous function that does the vectorized arithmetic on each piece of each of row. If that sounds vague, it's because your question is vague.

Comment: Are you doing this one line at a time or is there a certain way you match one line of A with one line of B & C?

Comment: @SeñorO - One line at a time in Dataframe A, and yes the colors (red, blue, etc.) represent the classes that I summarized on. So, in line 1 of Dataframe A, it would use the line "red" in Dataframe B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Merge by `group`

```
BigDataFrame <- merge(DataFrameA, DataFrameB, DataFrameC, by="group")
```

2) Evaluate within scope of new `data.frame`

```
with(BigDataFrame, (((a - b)/c)^2))
```

Comment: Cool. Never heard of/used "with" before. Thx!

Comment: Um...some additional work is required to merge more than 2 data frames I think...?